# How to prevent "Windows Features" popup on system start in Windows 8?

Tags: windows, .net-framework

I've started installing some program but after noticing that it requires the .NET framework, I canceled the installation. Since then this popup appears whenever I start the system:

[image]

How can I prevent this from appearing every time?

Comment: Make sure the program you were installing is completely uninstalled (ie. go to control panel > programs and features > uninstall the program you cancelled).

Comment: why don't you simply install .net 3.5?

Comment: @shub That turned out to be it. I looked once before, but couldn't find it. Now I've found the program and uninstalled it and the message doesn't appear anymore.

Comment: @magicandre1981 Why didn't Windows install it by default?

Comment: Windows 8 has a new feature: "features on demand" whee several features can be removed from WinSxS and if you need it you can install it again: http://blogs.technet.com/b/joscon/archive/2012/11/20/features-on-demand-in-windows-8-and-windows-server-2012.aspx Microsoft thinks that .net 3.5 is too old to include it by default.

Comment: @magicandre1981 I see. I guess I'd prefer to not install programs that rely on older Windows components like .NET 3.5.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably because part, or all, of the program you were trying to install is still on the computer.

AFAIK, some installers 'rollback' any changes made to the computer if the user clicks cancel, but some do not (which is probably the type of installer you used).

You should easily be able to fix this by making sure the program is *fully* uninstalled. You can do this by going to Control Panel > Programs and Features > find your program and uninstall.

You can sort the programs by name or date installed to easily find the program

Answer (score 0):

It seems that there is an autorun program need  .NET framework 3.5. To make that application work well, you`d better to install .NET framework 3.5 for that application.

You could try to perform a clean boot or use Autoruns tool to capture the culprit. Of course, you could uninstall that application if you don't want to use it anymore.

Clean boot

https://support.microsoft.com/en-sg/help/929135/how-to-perform-a-clean-boot-in-windows

Autoruns for Windows v13.7

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396